# how do you return only those documents with a specific character and term?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm learning elasticsearch and the first thing I have to do I retreive all the documents that have a specific element in their value.

For example, I have a documents that has a key of `origin` with values of:

- `/production/components/docs`
- `/default/another-example-docs`
- `/docs/development/category/user`
- etc

The results should return any `origin` document that has the element `/docs`, at the end or at the beginning.

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "origin": {
        "value": "docs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This also returns the `-docs` documents which I don't want. I have tried other queries but the same results. I have also tried using wildcards. I thought this would be straightforward but I was waaaay wrong. Any hints?

version: 8.9

Answer (score 0):

Okay, elasticsearch has build-in "prefix" query, so starts-with is pretty simple, but endsWith is much much more complicated. Im sure you can find some difficult and maybe more performant ways of doing this, using custom field analysers, custom tokenizers or\and some hacks with regexp( because elk does not support ^, $ flags).

I purpose simple solution, maybe not ideal, because script queries are worse in performance, but it will work.

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "prefix": {
        "origin": {
          "value": "/docs"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "script": {
        "script": """ if (doc['origin'].size() != 0 && doc['origin'].value.endsWith('/docs')) { return true } return false """
      }
    }
  ],
  "minimum_should_match": 1
}
}
}
```

Ofk you can put everything into 1 script query adding additional **startsWith** check

Comment: make sure that "origin" field is a keyword because prefix query may work not the same on text fields.